# How can i get postmessage data from react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postmessage

I'm trying to load a react url as an iframe in my jsp project.

Here my sender side code block:

```
<iframe id="eda" 
               style="display: none;"
                src="http://myhost:3000/"
                width="100%" height="600" border="0" marginwidth="0"
                marginheight="0" scrolling="no">
</iframe>   

****

function loadReactIframe(){
    document.getElementById("eda").contentWindow.postMessage('GET MESSAGE FROM ME', '*');
}
```

I also tried the following:

```
function loadReactIframe(){
      document.getElementById("eda").contentWindow.postMessage(
            'GET MESSAGE FROM ME', 
            'http://myhost', 3000
     );
}
```

My recevier (react) code block:

```
componentDidMount() {
     window.addEventListener('load', this.handleLoad);
     alert('componentDidMount')
}

handleLoad(event) {
     alert(event.data);
}
```

But i can not get the data from event.

Comment: Try this... `window.addEventListener('message', function(event){ });`

Comment: message event couldn't catch post message. :/

Comment: Your receiver is inside `iframe`, right??

Comment: Yes, my receiver is a react project, i'm calling it from a jsp project in iframe.

Comment: Check whether `loadReactIframe` is called after listener initialization...

Comment: Thank you very much, i forgot that. now it is working :)

Answer (score 3):

There is already a useful hook made for this. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rottitime/react-hook-message-event

Readme page has the instructions but here is a idea of how it works
Install the hook:

```
npm i @rottitime/react-hook-message-event
```

In your component use it as you would with any other hook such e.g. `useState`.

Import the file in your component

```js
import {useMessage} from '@rottitime/react-hook-message-event'
```

You can listen to a message and use a callback to respond. For example take the following scenario:

1. Parent window listens for the message `hello` from child window
2. Parent receives `hello` from child
3. Parent sends back `world` to child

```js
//listens for the 'hello' message from window.postMessage()
useMessage('hello', (send, payload) => {
  //use sendMessage to post back to the sender
  send({ type: 'world', success: true });
});
```